# NextJS firebase emulator functions keeps compiling, deleting and rebuilding next.js server until timeout occurs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, next.js, firebase-hosting

My site built with NextJs runs fine in dev mode and as a production build. After following the steps in online articles to get it running in cloud functions, a page visit results in the cloud function repeatedly deleting and recreating the `.next` folder and timing out about 50% of the time.

Answer (score 3):

This solution for me was in the next.config.js -- (`dev: false`):

```
const nextjsServer = next({
  dev: false, 
  ...
})
```

Up until recently, even the official vercel example had this incorrect ([see here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-firebase-hosting) for an up to date reference)

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/21971#discussion_r572753472

> I've changed that because the development mode caused a lot of confusion previously (see [#8893](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8893)). You cannot run next in development mode inside the cloud function.

What a fun 8 hours that was.  Give me an upvote if I saved you some time.